# Evaluate limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} }{x^{100}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Evaluate limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} }{x^{100}}$$

Just applying L'Hôpital's rule several times doesn't lead to anything except denominator grows bigger:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} }{x^{100}}\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} }{100\cdot x^{102}} \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{4e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} }{100\cdot 102 \cdot x^{104}} $$
And so on.
I can try to rewrite $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} }{x^{100}}$ as: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \exp(\frac{-1}{x^2} - 100 \ln x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \exp(\frac{-1 - 100x^2 \ln x}{x^2})$$
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-1 - 100x^2 \ln x}{x^2}$ after applying L'Hôpital's 2 times turns into $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-100(2 \ln x + 3)}{2}$. Hence,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \ln x = -\infty \implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-100(2 \ln x + 3)}{2} = + \infty \implies \lim_{x \to 0} \exp(\frac{-1}{x^2} - 100 \ln x) = + \infty $$

But answer in my textbook is $0$ without any explanation why.
I suspect, that I've made several huge mistakes, but hours of thinking haven't lead me to anything, unfortunately. So can you help me?

Comment: You miss because when $x$ gets really small $-1/x^2$ absolutely dominates $100\ln x$. Try $x=0.01$, which will be small enough to see this.

Comment: exponential always beats polynomial

Comment: @OscarLanzi yes, that's right. But I still don't understand how to use this fact to solve this question and come to right answer. Also author of the book applied  l'Hôpital. I can't see how he did that. That's what I am most interested in

Comment: You can flip the fraction and see what happens as $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $t=1/x^2$, hence $t\to+\infty$ when $x \to 0$. Moreover, it is $t^{50}=1/x^{100}$. So:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^{100}}=\lim_{t\to+\infty}t^{50}e^{-t}=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{t^{50}}{e^t}$$
Noticing that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is $\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}t^n}(t^n)=n!$, applying De Hôpital's $50$ times it is:
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{t^{50}}{e^t}=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{50!}{e^t}=0$$
A similar argument can be used to prove that any real power goes to $0$ when divided by $e^t$ when $t\to+\infty$ (see @Fix comment).

Comment: Thank you! This is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to apply de Hôpital just once. The limit, according to @Bernkastel is equal $$\lim_{t\to \infty}{t^{50}\over e^t}= \lim_{t\to \infty }\left ({t\over e^{t/50}}\right )^{50}=\lim_{u\to \infty}\left ({50u\over e^u}\right )^{50}$$ We get $$\lim_{u\to \infty}{u\over e^u}=0$$ by applying de Hôpital rule.